# stargazer Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: r, panel-data, stargazer

I'm to apply stargazer with "wbm"

this is my model

```r
modelMQ <- wbm(Management_Q ~ Emergency | Teaching, data = Pnurses)
```

but when I try to use stargazer

```
stargazer(modelMQ, Type = "text", title = "Hybrid", out="Hybrid.csv", align=TRUE , no.space = TRUE)
```

I get this error

> Error in objects[[i]]$zelig.call :
> $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Does anybody know how I can solve that? I use the same for lm and it works perfectly

Comment: The stargazer package does not handle all possible models. It's been specifically written to support certain models. and [wbm is not in the list of supported models](https://rdrr.io/cran/stargazer/man/stargazer_models.html).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there are another package that support this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of model does not appear to be supported by `stargazer`, but it is [supported by the `modelsummary` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

```r
library(panelr)
library(modelsummary)

wages <- panel_data(WageData, id = id, wave = t)
mod <- wbm(lwage ~ union, data = dat)

modelsummary(mod)
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| union | 0.055 |
|  | (0.025) |
| (Intercept) | 6.675 |
|  | (0.021) |
| imean(union) | 0.003 |
|  | (0.036) |
| SD (Intercept) | 0.382 |
| SD (Observations) | 0.259 |
| Num.Obs. | 4165 |
| R2 Marg. | 0.000 |
| R2 Cond. | 0.685 |
| AIC | 2262.8 |
| BIC | 2294.5 |
| RMSE | 0.24 |